# How do I prevent mule from encoding the query-param?

Tags: encoding, mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

In a HTTP request, I am adding a token as a query-param. 
It seems that mule is encoding the value. 
- If I add the parameter, mule will encode it in the way it is wrong. 
- If I add already encoded parameter, mule will double encode it and therefore won't be usable anymore.

So the question is: Is there a way or a workaround to prevent mule from encoding the URL query-param?

Example of the parameter: {AES}ZEoksxIg484magPtWwNUUQ==;iT0kI2HsqGkh%2Bdc2baW2B4dNR2vouKkWQsDTdbMP8us=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague found a workaround for this, so I'm sharing it here.

Apparently, you can **set a variable** before the HTTP request and add the manually encoded value. Let's call it `ourTokenVariable` In my example above that would be `%7BAES%7DZEoksxIg484magPtWwNUUQ%3D%3D%3BiT0kI2HsqGkh%252Bdc2baW2B4dNR2vouKkWQsDTdbMP8us%3D`

After that, you can use this newly created variable directly in the url path. For example: `/example/someapi?someToken=[#flowvars.ourTokenVariable]`

This way you don't need to use `uri-param` or `query-param` anymore (where mule is double encoding the value). The value will be taken 'as is'.